# How can I have the UIScroll effect similar to the one on AirBNB iOS App as the pic below

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I need to be able to apply the scrolling effect similar to the one found in iOS AirBNB where when you scroll the UI collection view cell image gets highlighted

I'm unable to have the scrolling happening and one cell to get stopped and selected.

[image: iOS AirBNB App Collection View Scroll]

What I have done so far:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 2.3
    let hardCodedPadding:CGFloat = 15
    let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow) - hardCodedPadding
    let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * hardCodedPadding)
    return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
}
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems[0].row, section: 0)
    
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.left, animated: true)
    (collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! productImageCell).productImage.layer.borderWidth = 5
    
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    let cellWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / 3)
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5 , 0, cellWidth/3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you have to do is to use `UICollectionViewDelegate`, `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, you should also create some important variables

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    // Used to calculate the position after the user end dragging
    var cellWidth: CGFloat? 

    // Used to set the layout for the collectionView
    var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout? 

    // The collection view
    var collectionView: UICollectionView?
}
```

Next, you're going to create instantiate the layout and collection view, set some parameters, add the collection view to the view and finally register our cell class. This can be done in your `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // You can change the width of the cell for whatever you want
    cellWidth = view.frame.width*0.5

    // instantiate the layout, set it to horizontal and the minimum line spacing
    layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout?.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout?.minimumLineSpacing = 0 // You can also set to whatever you want

    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout!)
    cv.backgroundColor = .green
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    collectionView = cv
    collectionView?.allowsSelection = true

    guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
        return
    }

    // Add to subview
    view.addSubview(collectionView)

    // Set auto layout constraints
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true

    // Register cell class
    collectionView.register(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

}
```

The last thing to do in your `ViewController` is to select the correct cell after the user end dragging, you're going to use the `scrollViewWillEndDragging(...)` method for that:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    guard let cellWidth = cellWidth else {
        return
    }

    var cellNumber = 0
    let offsetByCell = targetContentOffset.pointee.x/cellWidth

    // If the user drag just a little, the scroll view will go to the next cell
    if offsetByCell > offsetByCell + 0.2 {
        cellNumber = Int(ceilf(Float(offsetByCell)))
    } else {
        cellNumber = Int(floorf(Float(offsetByCell)))
    }

    // Avoiding index out of range exception
    if cellNumber < 0 {
        cellNumber = 0
    }

    // Avoiding index out of range exception
    if cellNumber >= (collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: 0))! {
        cellNumber = (collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: 0))! - 1
    }

    // Move to the right position by using the cell width, cell number and considering the minimum line spacing between cells
    targetContentOffset.pointee.x = cellWidth * CGFloat(cellNumber) + (CGFloat(cellNumber) * (layout?.minimumLineSpacing)!)

    // Scroll and select the correct item
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: cellNumber, section: 0)
    collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
    collectionView?.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .left)
}
```

This is everything that you have to set in your view controller.

Finally, the last thing that you have to do in your code is to go to your custom cell (in my case `MyCollectionViewCell`) and add an observer to the `selected` property, in my class I'm just changing the background color of the selected cell, but you can put any logic that you want:

```
import UIKit

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = isSelected ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.white
        }
    }

    override init (frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Hopefully it can help you accomplish what you need.

Comment: for some reason the above didn't work. What I have done is copy and paste the code as is to see how the effect is going to look like

Comment: I have copied and pasted the above in a new project but it didn't work. Did you put it together to give me some ideas or to be working as is and can see the scrolling and if I want to add my stuff I can?